# Passing the same markup reference into SpannableString.setSpan results in overwrite of previous spans

Tags: android, spannablestring

I'm building a little utilitary class to deal with Spannables. But using the same `Markup object` doesn't work.

```
      Object span = new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD);

      SpannableString test = new SpannableString("Hello this is a test");     

   // This doesn't work. The last setSpan overwrites the first one
      test.setSpan(span,0,4,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      test.setSpan(span,10,13,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

   // This works because it's a new reference 
      test.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),0,4,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      test.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),10,13,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Is there anyway I can work around and use the same reference ? Maybe changing the flags ? I already looked it up but no success.

Comment: There's definitely an '==' check in the implementation of `setSpan` on the `what` object causing the overwrite.  Would `SpannableStringBuilder` possibly work for you?  There is no similar check in its `setSpan`.

Comment: Alright, care to give me an example and I shall accept it as a workaround ?